# How can I pass partial inputs to dropdown list in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having one option button. The values inside the option button looks like "Cat animal", "Parrot bird", "crocodile reptile". Now I need to pass the partial input as "Cat" to the option button and so that "Cat animal" should get selected. How can i do so. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What method are you using to find elements? Can you post a snippet of the html or a sample?

Comment: Hi Alexxp03..! I used function: indexOf and method: new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("pkFinalite"))).selectByIndex(Matched_Index); and I got the output than q so much..!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below html snippet

```
<select id='Combo'>
   <option value="test1234"> Hello World</option>
   <option value="test2345"> Stack overflow </option>
</select>
```

Here is the logic for select options using partial text & values

```
By select = By.id("Combo");
String partialText="overflow"

SelectByPartialText
driver.findElement(select).findElement(By.xpath(".//option[contains(text(),'"+partialText+"')]")).click();

SelectByPartialValue
driver.findElement(select).findElement(By.xpath(".//option[contains(@value,'1234')]")).click();
```